# Image won't clear when saved from Tkinter canvas

Tags: python, image, canvas, tkinter, save

I'm making a handwritten digit interpreter with Tkinter using a model I made.  I save the canvas image, then read it back through my model to get the prediction.  I clear the canvas with cv.delete("all") then I draw another digit to predict and I get a wonky prediction.

Initial Outcome: (3 is 3 :)!!!)
[image: Picture of it working]

Then I clear it and write another number:
[image: Picture of it not working]

And I go to my folder where the image saves and the picture looks like this:
[image: Picture of the 4 and 3 on top of eachother all weird]

Here's my code to define my canvas and the image I'm going to draw on.

```
# define the canvas and image to save
lastx, lasty = None, None

cv = Canvas(root, width=420, height=420, bg='black')
image1 = PIL.Image.new("L",(420,420),"black")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image1)

cv.bind('<1>', activate_paint)
cv.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
```

Here's the code I used to paint:

```
 def activate_paint(e):
    global lastx, lasty
    cv.bind('<B1-Motion>', paint)
    lastx, lasty = e.x, e.y

def paint(e):
    global lastx, lasty
    x, y = e.x, e.y
    cv.create_line((lastx, lasty, x, y), fill = 'white',width=30)
    #  --- PIL
    draw.line((lastx, lasty, x, y), fill='white', width=30)
    lastx, lasty = x, y
```

And here's the code I use to save it when I click the predict button:

```
filename = f'img_to_predict.png'
image1.save(filename)
```

I just need the clear button to make the image truly blank so it doesn't save over the previous image.  Can anyone push me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Jackson

Comment: You need to clear the image as well by calling `draw.rectangle((0, 0, 420, 420), fill="black")`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear the image as well by calling

```
draw.rectangle((0, 0, 420, 420), fill="black")
```

However, I would propose to remove drawing on the image.  Just drawing on the canvas, and then take a snapshot on the canvas using `ImageGrab.grab()` (from `Pillow` module as well) and save the snapshot to file when you need to do the prediction:

```
# get the canvas bounding box on screen
x, y = cv.winfo_rootx(), cv.winfo_rooty()
w, h = cv.winfo_width(), cv.winfo_height()
# take a snapshot on the canvas and save the image to file
ImageGrab.grab((x, y, x+w, y+h)).save('img_to_predict.png')
```

Comment: Your first bit of code did the trick.  Thank you!  How would my code be different to draw on the canvas instead of drawing on the image?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: This doesn't seem to matter at all, so please ignore it

Assuming you copy pasted the line `cv.delete("all")`, the issue might be using "all" as a string. You might need `cv.delete(ALL)` to clear it away?

Comment: Actually `ALL` is equal to `'all'` in `tkinter`.

Comment: Thank you for your response!  This didn't fix the problem...  I'll try your other solution now.